# Creating a RAISE EXCEPTION to validate the data types in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, plpgsql

Does anyone know if you can create an ELEVATION EXCEPTION to be displayed when you enter an incorrect data type? example obviously it does not work but it's an example of what I'm looking for

```
CREATE TABLE products(
  name_pr varchar(20),
  quantity smallint,
  price smallint,
  last_update timestamp,
  latest_user_bd text
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_products()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

  IF NEW.price IS NOT SMALLINT THEN
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'You must enter the Price';
  END IF;

  NEW.last_update = now();
  NEW.latest_user_bd = user;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER validate_products
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON products
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_products();
```

example insert into C#

```
string query = "INSERT INTO products(name_pr, quantity, price) VALUES('" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtQuantity.Text + "','" + txtPrice.Text + "')";
con.Open();
comand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
```

Comment: Em, if the data is not `smallint` i expect you would get an exception anyway because postgres can't fit that in?

Comment: What about validating it on the C# side?  It looks like what you want to accomplish can be done before actually sending the command to Postgres.  Also, if you parameterize the query, that will make it bulletproof even if it does go.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot to trigger outer exceptions in Postgres of TOP command. You can pass parameters to PostgreSQL function, and there you can run command in protected block. There you can handle the exception. Some like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_product(__price text)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE _price smallint;
BEGIN
  _price := __price::smallint;
  INSERT INTO product(..) (_price);
EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_text_representation, numeric_value_out_of_range THEN
  IF price IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'the price is not valid smallint value %', _price;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don't like this "untyped" function - but it does, what you want.

On second hand PostgreSQL types are not variant types, so pattern

```
IF some IS NOT smallint THEN -- has not sense
```

is nonsense in PLpgSQL. You can use regexp, you can use `numeric` and tests on limits, or you can cast to smallint and catch the exception.

PLpgSQL is strict typed language (PostgreSQL SQL too), so some pattern from dynamic less typed languages are not possible there.

Usually the types and their values should be checked first on UI level - and secondary it should be apply safely on SQL level. SQL level does recheck, but it can raise a common exception. The parameter check is better task for presentation layer.